# Scrapy. Send a link in Selector

Tags: python, scrapy, response

When building a spider came across an interesting thing - you need to pass a reference to the function to it, in turn, sent in the Selector. Tried already all available Response and Request methods Scrapy, but the data do not come.

A piece of code to understand:

```
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.site.ru/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):  
        sel = Selector(response)
        self.links = sel.xpath('//*[@id="col-01"]/div/div/ul/li/a/@href').extract()

    def parse_catalog(self, response): 
        sel = Selector(response)
        elements = sel.xpath('//*[@id="col-01"]/div[1]/ul[1]/
                                        li[4]/div[2]/strong/text()').extract()[0]
        links_auto = sel.xpath('//div[@class="car-detail-list"]/a/@href').extract()

        for link in links_auto:
            self.parse_page(link)

    def parse_page(self, link):
        response = ??? (link)
        self.sel = Selector(response)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to yield a new Request from the `parse_catalog` method. Send it with `parse_link` as the callback, and it will work exactly like the regular parse methods.

```
start_urls = [
    "http://www.site.ru/"
]

def parse(self, response):  
    sel = Selector(response)
    self.links = sel.xpath('//*[@id="col-01"]/div/div/ul/li/a/@href').extract()

def parse_catalog(self, response): 
    sel = Selector(response)
    elements = sel.xpath('//*[@id="col-01"]/div[1]/ul[1]/
                                    li[4]/div[2]/strong/text()').extract()[0]
    links_auto = sel.xpath('//div[@class="car-detail-list"]/a/@href').extract()

    for link in links_auto:
        yield Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_page) # Request is sent

def parse_page(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response) # Response is picked up
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already familiar. I wanted to use some of the methods of Response-Request for a more flexible definition.

Comment: `extract()` returns an array of elements. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Get HTML for processing selector